How can I open a hyperlink in Edge via ctrl+f using only keyboard shortcuts and not esc?
My question is very similar to this one, except I'm asking for Edge: I want to open a hyperlink by keyboard shortcut using the ctrl + f search tool and without needing to first press esc. In Chrome, the solution is, and apparently has been for almost 10 years, ctrl + enter.
Per a friend over at StackOverflow, there's no keyboard shortcut for this on Edge. I'm posting here in case someone is aware of one and also because it was shamed for being a non-programming question over there.
